# PHP if date equals then

Tags: php, mysql, date, datepicker

Hi I'm trying use a datepicker on a field I have. I'm trying to set the date field up so the user can only edit this field if the date value in the database is set to deafault (0000-00-00). If there is a value that's not equal to default I want to show the date created.

Here's the code I have attempted:

```
          if( $post['Date'] = var_dump(checkdate(00, 00, 0000))){ 
          echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"datepicker\" name=\"pDate\" style=\"border:#000099; margin:10px;\" value=\"";
          echo $post['Date'];
          echo "\"> <input id=\"start_dt\" class=\"datepicker\">";
          }
          if( $post['Date'] != var_dump(checkdate(00, 00, 0000))){ 
          echo "<span>date created: </span>";
          echo $post['Date'];

          }
```

It's not working atm so any help or a point in the right direction would be great.
Please also take into account I haven't added any proper styling so I'm only after help with the functionality.

Many thanks.

Comment: The [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Don't use var_dump() in this way... var_dump() is a developers' debugging statement, not a method of displaying data to end users, nor of parsing values for if tests

Comment: `var_dump` is for debug-outputting variables and does not return anything. So with `$post['Date'] = var_dump(...)` you are assigning `null` to `$post['Date']` and `null` evaluates to `false`, so your condition is never met.

Comment: Are you referring to post variables by `$post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is used for debugging purpose rather than inside conditional expression. Next, using `=` assigns the values not checks for them. You are assigning the values of `var_dump()` results to `$post['Date']` So change them to `==`

You should be trying to to something like this

```
  if( $post['Date'] == checkdate(00, 00, 0000)){ 
      echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"datepicker\" name=\"pDate\" style=\"border:#000099; margin:10px;\" value=\"".$post['Date']"\">";
      echo "<input id=\"start_dt\" class=\"datepicker\">";
  } else {
      echo "<span>date created: </span>";
      echo $post['Date'];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't want to use `var_dump()`. But it would help if you told us the structure of the value of `$post['Date']`.
2. You want to use `==`, not `=` for your first `if` statement. You should be comparing, not assigning, (a) value(s).
3. The second `if` statement can just be changed to an `else`.
4. Just checking, but do you mean `$_POST['Date']` rather than `$post['Date']`?

Comment: I am running a query to get the date from the database, basically what I'm wanting to do is if ((My database date) equals (the default date)){  Do something...

Answer (score 0):

No need to invent anything:
`$post['Date'] == '0000-00-00'`

Also, you should use `NULL` instead of default in most cases.